# Evaluating DateTime.Now.Millisecond in a loop - C#

Tags: c#, timer, milliseconds

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to evaluate time in milliseconds using `System.Timer`, to break out of a `while` loop when `current time` matches the `past time + a number of milliseconds` (which meets the future condition).

Sometimes it exits the loop successfully but other times it runs as an infinite loop. I am thinking that it has something to do with the milliseconds clock precision, but I'm not sure. A Console output of the variables shows `timeFuture` to be correct.

I've looked at `Timespan` but not sure how to use that. Many thanks for any feedback.

```
long end = 500;  //500 milliseconds
long timeStart = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;  //time in milliseconds
long timeFuture = timeStart + end;
long timeNow = 0;

while (true)
{
    timeNow = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;              
    if (timeFuture - timeNow == 0) { break; }             
    Console.WriteLine(timeNow);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using a `Timer`, given that you even know about using timers?

Comment: First read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx then

Comment: Your algorithm would theoretically work if you were able to do the comparison every millisecond, but due to limited speed, multi-tasking,a accuracy etc, you are not able to do this. The simplest fix would be to compare '< 0' instead of '== 0' (but there are better solutions to what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: @Servy - as an experiment really - my real interest is knowing about how music sequencers like Ableton and so on, use time, what their techniques are. But I'm also a complete beginner in programming and touching on subjects which really are too advanced for me, at this stage - so I'm dabbling with novice stuff as well as reading up on the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.Milisecond` doesn't return the time in miliseconds, but the actual milisecond at the point in time that the `DateTime` instance represents (so it will always be between 0 and 999). Additionally,  as you are running on a multi-threaded system, your condition might never be executed at the exact point in time when it would evaluate to `true` (writing to the console consumes time as well).

So you might consider changing your condition and make use of the `Timespan` class:

```
DateTime timeStart = DateTime.Now;

while (true)
{
  DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan difference = (timeNow - timeStart);
  if (difference.TotalMilliseconds >= 500) { break; }
  Console.WriteLine(timeNow);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers a lot! I was aware that there would be an issue going from 999 back to 0 (as it's acting on the whole date) but wasn't sure how to implement the TimeSpan class. Also that there would be an issue of there not being an exact point, but how this ties into multi-threaded... that's over my head for now.

Answer (score 0):

Millisecond is the component of the time, not a time span. You want something like

```
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while (true)
    {

        if ((DateTime.Now - start ).TotalMilliseconds>500) // Is a timespan
          { break; }             
        Console.WriteLine(timeNow);
    }
```